# Div. Combine precentage and fixed size

Tags: css, dynamic, html, height

Is it possible? div "menu" and "submenu" needs to be 50px tall. "top" and "bottom" needs to be 60% and 40%. The behinde-the-scene-calculation would be 60% - 50px for "top".

```
<div id="menu"></div>
<div id="top">
</div>
<div id="submenu"></div>    
<div id="bottom">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS doesn't mix units to let you say 60% - 50px -- to achieve something like this effect, you'd have to resort to JavaScript to compute the sizes.

If your div's are directly inside , you won't have to re-implement too much of a layout engine -- at document load, get the viewport size, then compute what 60% - 50px is in pixels and assign that as the #top element height, and similarly for #bottom.

Comment: To solve it with JavaScript you have to compute when the window resizes. Not only on document load. Thats my last option. Rather go with frames...

Answer (score 1):

As you asking if you can do this? Because yes, you can

```
#menu, #submenu{
    height: 50px;
}
#top{
    height: 60%;
}
#bottom{
    height: 40%;
}
```

What would happen is both menus would be 50px, and then the top and bottom would take 60 and 40% of the page. Most likely you would have scrollbars because the page would be 100px over 100% of the page, but it is very possible.

You can mix percentages, pixels, and ems.

Comment: Although, the top and bottom as the code you wrote would take up 60 and 40 percent of the page. But it is very possible to do that.

Comment: You know that is not what he meant. He wants wants to divide the space remaining from header and footer 3:2.

Comment: If you want the entire thing to only equal 200px, just put it inside a div that have the height set to be 200px. Still not sure about the question though.